# How to select 70 percent of a column based on condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, select, sql-server-2016, percentage

This is my existing table data

```
C1 C2 C3
1  A  1                                                                                                  
2  B  1 
3  C  0 
4  D  0
5  E  0
6  F  0
7  G  1
8  H  1
9  I  1
10 J  0
```

I want to get this. What I am trying is I want to select 70% C3 column with value 1. In total the C3 has five ones. So 70% of 5 is 3.5 which is 4 ones. So I want to get my final dataset with 70 percent of ones in C3

```
C1 C2 C3
1  A  1  
2  B  1 
3  C  0 
4  D  0
5  E  0
7  G  1
8  H  1
```

Comment: If you want the 1's; why are there rows with `0` ion `C3` in the dataset as well?

Comment: I want the result set to be 70% of my entire dataset with 70%  of 1s in C3  and remaining as 0s. I need the 0s as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
select * 
from 
    (SELECT *,
        (SELECT SUM(C3) FROM table_name t1 WHERE t1.C1 <= t.C1) AS cumulative_sum,
        (select sum(C3) from table_name) as total_sum
    FROM table_name t) t
where (cumulative_sum - C3) < 0.8 * total_sum
```

Comment: This solution works but there is one small drawback - In this solution, it does not get me 70% of my entire dataset but it consistently brings back 70% of the values with 1 in C3 . Is there anyway to fix this so I get 70% of my entire dataset with 70% 1 values of C3 as I said in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You don't seem to want a *random* selection.  They seem to be ordered by `col1`.  So, you can calculate this as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when col3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by col1) as running_col3,
             sum(case when col3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over () as total_col3
      from t
     ) t
where running_col3 >= 0.8 * total_col3 and
      (running_col3 - col3) < 0.8 * total_col3;
```

Note:  If `col3` has only `0` and `1`, you can simplify the above to:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(col3) over (order by col1) as running_col3,
             sum(col3) over () as total_col3
      from t
     ) t
where running_col3 >= 0.8 * total_col3 and
      (running_col3 - col3) < 0.8 * total_col3
```

Comment: When I replace t with my table value like this
select t.*
from (select tablename.*,
             sum(col3) over (order by col1) as running_col3,
             sum(col3) over () as total_col3
      from tablename
     ) t
where running_col3 >= 0.8 * total_col3 and
      (running_col3 - col3) < 0.8 * total_col3

It gives me only one row in the result
I want to get 70% of my entire dataset with 70% 1 values of C3 in it

Comment: @learningtocode2k20 . . . You simply use `from tablename t`.  This is a better approach than using subqueries.

Comment: It throws an error with the syntax
(running_col3 - col3)
I am not able to replace it with COL3 it throws an error saying invalid column, I tried t.col3 still it shows error

Comment: @learningtocode2k20 . . . It is rather unclear why `col3` would not be defined.  It appears to be in your table and in the subquery.